# How to use PyArrow's `read_csv` to read a CSV with cusomer delimiter and no header?

Tags: python, csv, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a file that looks like

```
2|1|abc
3|4|def
```

```py
from pyarrow import csv

a = csv.read_csv("file.csv", parse_options=csv.ParseOptions(delimiter="|", header_rows=0))
```

So how do I specify *explicit column names*? Can't find it in the documentation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\data\dask\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-15-18e80408b284>", line 2, in <module>
    a = csv.read_csv("c:/data/Performance_All/Performance_2003Q3.txt", parse_options=csv.ParseOptions(delimiter="|", header_rows=0))
  File "pyarrow\_csv.pyx", line 450, in pyarrow._csv.read_csv
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 85, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: header_rows == 0 needs explicit column names
```

Comment: in `pandas` to read/write csv without headers you have to use `None`, not `0`. Maybe here is the same. And "explicit" may means you have to use `header_rows = ["name of header 1", "name of header 2"]`

Comment: The documentation says `header_rows` is an `int` see https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.ParseOptions.html#pyarrow.csv.ParseOptions and It tried your suggestion and it gives error "TypeError: an integer is required"

Comment: in source code I see `column_names` in [ReadOptions](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/_csv.pyx#L57). There is description that If it is empty then it reads names from file. Probably if you assign names to `column_names` then it will not read them from file.

Comment: it's not in the v14 version that I am using https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/maint-0.14.x/python/pyarrow/_csv.pyx

Answer (score 3):

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6231. We are discussing automatic assignment of column names -- your feedback would be useful. In the meantime, you must pass explicit column names.

Comment: _How_ do I pass explicit column names? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @xiaodai It's in the git master, but not in a released version yet.

Answer (score 3):

The `column_names` parameter was added in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-5747, which will be included in the 0.15 release.